# Таблице виртуальных функции класса наследника пуста или вообще не создается?

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть два класса, второй класс наследует первого. В базовом классе имеются виртуальные функции а в наследнике нет виртуальних функции. Что будет находится в таблице виртуальных функции класса наследника, она пуста или вообще не создаются ?

```
class base
{
  private:
    int m_d;
  public:
    virtual void foo();
    virtual void bar();
};

class derived : public base
{
    int m_b;
    void baz();
};
```

Comment: скорее всего в втором классе будет ссылка на таблицу виртуальных функций предка. Но компилятор не обязан делать код через таблицу виртуальных функций. Просто это самый простой способ реализации наследования.

Если честно, то компилятор может вообще выкинуть таблицы виртуальных функций, если он по коду может точно рассчитать, какая именно функция и когда будет вызвана.

Comment: Примерно час назад меня интервьюировали по телефону, на этот вопрос я ответил, что таблица виртуальних функции класса наследника будет пусто, это очень грубый и неточный ответ ?

Comment: Пустой она не может быть, как тогда вызывать вирт. функции?

Comment: Обязательная ссылка: http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html

Перечитывать до прихода сатори.

Comment: @Вардан: правильный ответ — таблица виртуальных методов есть деталь реализации в некоторых компиляторах и не гарантирована по стандарту.

Comment: Спасибо всем

Answer (score 2):

В таблице `derived` будут указатели на `base::foo()` и `base::bar()`